# AngularJS Date filter showing wrong date

Tags: javascript, datetime, angularjs

I have seen lots of confusion with TimeZones and Angular Date filters, but my issue seems a little different.

I am storing all dates and times in the database as UTC.

The following code snippet -

```
{{release.createdDateTime}} {{release.createdDateTime | date:'dd/MM/yyyy [H:mm:ss]'}}
```

produces this output **(notice the incorrect minutes)**:

```
2013-08-17T14:28:54.1020000Z 17/08/2013 [15:45:54]
```

I am struggling to work out what the issue might be.

Comment: It is taking your local timezone

Comment: That doesn't explain the change in the minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Try below will show you date with time zone it is displaying: format('dd/MM/yyyy [H:mm:ss]Z')

```
{{release.createdDateTime}} {{release.createdDateTime | date:'dd/MM/yyyy [H:mm:ss]Z'}}
```

Comment: Adding the Z changes it to:

2013-08-17T14:28:54.1020000Z 17/08/2013 [15:45:54]+0100

Answer (score 0):

If your date is coming from MySQL, and you're using php, convert it to ISODate format first.

```
date("c", strtotime($mysqlDateValueFromDb))
```

ISO dates are in the format: `2005-08-15T15:52:01+0000` (DATE_ISO8601)

The standard angularJS date filters will work out of the box.